# check if items in array existed and add new values from another array without overwriting?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check if items in array existed and add new values from another array without overwriting element after reloading. I created such code:

```
//take from that array
    List<int> list = [2, 3, 5];
  // add to this array and check if this array already has the same element or not    
      List<int> newValueInt = [2, 6, 7];
    
      list.forEach((item) {
        if(!list.contains(item)){
          newValueInt.add(item);
          print(newValueInt);
        }  
      });
```

and it shows me that print:

```
     [2, 6, 7, 3]
[2, 6, 7, 3, 5]
```

Comment: `!list.contains(item)` is always false because you are calling `list.forEach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<int> list = [2, 3, 5];
  // add to this array and check if this array already has the same element or not
  List<int> newValueInt = [2, 6, 7];
  List<int> temp = [];
  for (var item in list) {
    if(!newValueInt.contains(item)){
      temp.add(item);
    }
  }

  List<int> result = newValueInt + temp;

  print(result); //---> [2, 6, 7, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!list.contains(item)){
```

to

```
if(! newValueInt.contains(item)){
```